# Can I get hold of Mega-Evolution stones for the other Kanto starters in Pokémon X&Y?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I've got to the part of the game where you can choose one of the Kanto region starters.

I'd like to train a Squirtle this time around but I also would really like to be able to see Charizard Y at some point.

I have a Charizard I can transfer up from Pokémon White but I need to know if the megastone for Charizard is something you can get even if you didn't pick Charmander from the Professor.

Comment: In Lumiose City there's a store for stones, in which an old man tried to sell me a Megastone for Ivysaur (even though I chose Squirtle). The stone itself is quite expensive.

Answer (score 8):

In **Lumiose City** there is a "**Stone Emporium**" that sells...stones.

If you go in, there's usually only a clerk that sells regular stones (*Fire, Leaf, Sun, etc.*).  However, to the left of the clerk there is a man who does sell the Mega Evolution stones.

Note, his prices are tremendously expensive, if you haven't defeated the Elite Four yet.  Defeating the Elite Four and the Champion should move the game into postgame, which drastically cuts down the prices for the stones.

Here are the stones he sells:

> **Main Game** (*before Elite Four*)
>
> - Charizardite X/Y - *1,000,000*
> - Venusaurite - *1,000,000*
> - Blastoisenite - *1,000,000*
>
> **Post Game** (*after Elite Four*)
>
> - Charizardite X/Y - *150,000*
> - Venusaurite - *150,000*
> - Blastoisenite - *150,000*

According to the Pokemon Guide, pointed out by BenBrocka, the price can get significantly lower based on how "stylish" you become:

[image]

Comment: I think you have this backwards... because it was $1,000,000 for me AFTER beating the elite four.

Comment: Shouldn't be, the wiki confirms that it is 150k post game

Comment: Maybe wiki is wrong? Because I went through the E4 and Champion about 15-20 times to save up the money to buy the additional stones, at 1Mil a piece.

Comment: @C-dizzle I can confirm the price was 1mil after defeating the first gym.   Wiki clearly states postgame that the the price becomes a mere 150k.

Comment: Given how recently the game was released, it is possible that the wiki is wrong about the exact condition that triggers the price drop, while being correct about the fact of the price drop. It's unlikely that the editor returned to the shop after every event that could possibly have set a flag.

Comment: Here is a quote from another "reliable" site... clearly wrong as well.
Blastoise
 Location. Blastoisenite is also provided by the Professor Sycamore along with the Pokemon. Pick Squirtle as your starter Pokemon and you will get this Mega Stone. Alternatively, you can buy this from Stone Emporium for 500,000 after completing the game; do remember though, it’s only available every three days.

Comment: According to the guide? the price drops as you become more stylish http://i.imgur.com/qcRZPpJ.jpg

Comment: @BenBrocka I would put that as an answer instead of a comment, since you have a reliable source with the correct info.

Answer (score 1):

I have not beaten the Elite Four, but I have bought the Stone for Charizard (I picked Bulbasaur) for a mere 10.000. I can confirm that Lumiose Style is the only relevant factor.
The original information provided in the previous answers probably comes from a source that checked only after doing several style-raising actions and beating the Elite Four without checking in-between.

For ways to raise your Style, check the picture in Retrosaurs answer.
One kind of lame way I have tested and can confirm is buying many Premier Balls one by one. Exiting the store or the buy dialog is not necessary, you can just select the Premier Ball and mash A. In my testing, roughly 120 Balls were enough, I've seen reports of less and have done Style-raising actions before that. My assumption is that with 0 Style, 150 should do.

I'm not sure what determines which Stone you get from him, but he only ever offered me Charizardite. While I didn't pay attention to the days and it might actually be related to when you talk to him, I think the third Stone might well be unlocked after beating the Elite Four, possibly only after upgrading your Mega Ring.

Answer (score -1):

You can buy it in Luminose city at the stone emporium for 150,000 after the elite four. Prior to that, they're 1,000,000.