# Mega Stone of chosen Starter Pokemon buyable?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

If I am choosing Charmander as my starter, will I be able to buy the Charizardite Mega Stone again?
So I could buy another one and trade it to someone else.

Edit:

I just found [this site](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/pokemon-x-and-y-guide-starters-strategies) and it says: "You can always try trading for them, of course, but, because each game contains just one of these items per playthrough, you'd have make a pretty persuasive offer."

Or [here](http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/18014/article/pokemon-x-and-y-mega-stones-locations-guide/) which says: "If you didn't get it from him, you will be able to buy it from a man in the Stone Emporium in Lumiose City in the postgame."
I'm not sure about the if here.

I want to be 100% sure about this. It sounds like you wont get the Mega Stone of your Starter twice.

Comment: Related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134208/can-i-get-hold-of-mega-evolution-stones-for-the-other-kanto-starters-in-pokemon/155771#155771

Answer (score 2):

Not for Charizard, at the **Stone Emporium** in Lumiose City you can buy for [1,000,000 before and (as low as) 10,000](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QgmyW.jpg) two other Mega Stones after you beat the Elite Four at the end of the story.

I bought Blastonite and Venusaurite. I can't only buy other Chairzardite Y or X it depends from your Pokemon version.

Comment: As well for my chosen starter Pokemon?

I just found [this site](http://www.usgamer.net/articles/pokemon-x-and-y-guide-starters-strategies) and it says: "You can always try trading for them, of course, but, because each game contains just one of these items per playthrough, you'd have make a pretty persuasive offer."

Or [here](http://www.gameranx.com/updates/id/18014/article/pokemon-x-and-y-mega-stones-locations-guide/) which says: "If you didn't get it from him, you will be able to buy it from a man in the Stone Emporium in Lumiose City in the postgame."
I'm not sure about the if here.

Comment: Didn't understand your question in first right. Sorry!

Comment: Oh okay, thanks. And you can buy every Mega Stone only one time?
So if you trade them you wont be able to get them again?

Comment: I'm not sure but probably they are gone. So be careful :)

Answer (score 1):

I was able to bring the price down to 10,000 before even having all the gym badges. You have to increase your style. Best way to do so is to go into the poke ball store and buy 100 premiere balls (the 200 ones) but buy them individually...each individual purchase in the town increases your style. I bought 100 of those balls seperately, did all the jobs in the hotel, did a couple of the battles in the resturaunts, and a couple water/fire stones from the stone store. That brought down the price to 10,000 with only my 5 gym badges. If he doesn't drop down to 10,000 go back and buy 10 more balls and keep going back and forth until it drops

Comment: Confirming that, I had done a few style-raising things and it was down to 10.000 after roughly 120 Premier Balls. I also had 5 or  badges at the time.

Answer (score 1):

Each of the Mega Stones is available **exactly once per save file**.
You receive the Stone for the Starter you pick from Prof. Sycamore and won't be able to get a second one. The Stones for the other 2 Starters can be bought from the guy left of the counter in Lumiose's Stone Emporium store (details in a [related question](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/134208/can-i-get-hold-of-mega-evolution-stones-for-the-other-kanto-starters-in-pokemon/155771#155771)), but he will only sell you one of each (I believe actually only one prior to beating the Elite Four and the last one after that, but it might be related to the day you talk to him).

The Charizardite exclusive to the Version you're not playing is not obtainable at all.

So to sum it up, assuming you are playing X, you can receive **1 Venusaurite, 1 Blastoisite, 1 Charizardite X** and **0 Charizardite Y**. If you're playing Y, the Charizardites are reversed.

The only way to get additional ones is to (1) trade for them online or (2) trade them to a friend, erase the save file, start a new adventure and get back the Stones you sent to your friend.

By the way, this applies to all other Mega Stones as well. There is **no way to obtain more than one of each Mega Stone** without playing through the game twice or trading for it.

Answer (score 0):

Ok this is what I am gathering from all this - the guy in the stone emporium will only sell you the mega evolution stones of the two pokemon you didnt choose from Sycamore and depending on how much style you have ( http://www.serebii.net/xy/lumiosestyle.shtml ) it can cost as little as 10,000 but that will only be after you beat the elite 4 since one of the things you have to do is be tougher than the champion for the battle institute. Also what i gather is that if you dont choose Charmander the only stone he will sell for Charizard is the exclusive version of your game so if you are playing X you wont get Charizardite Y

Comment: The Elite Four are not related to this. Style is the only relevant factor. I've bought the Stone for 10.000 with less than all badges. Also you'll only ever get your versione exclusive Charizardite, even if you pick Charmander. The Professor will give you the version exclusive one and the Stone guy only sells the Stones for the other 2 Starters.

Answer (score -1):

On Vernal Avenue in the Stone Emporium, there is a man in the back to the left of the stone counter. He is the guy who gives you the Mega Stones, and it can actually be done before beating the elite four. The problem is, The price is really big, P1,000,000 (P is the currency symbol). However, It seems over time, the stone decreases in value. I'm not exactly sure how, but it does. The easiest way to get money for it is to go to the Battle Chateau on Route 7, have one of your Pokemon hold and Amulet Coin, and do battles. These guys will give BIG payouts, especially the higher ranking ones. The highest I ever got with an Amulet coin was over P12,000! Do that, and you'll have those stones in no time.