# How long do you have to wait between buying both Mega Stones from Stone Emporium Pokemon X (or Y)?

Tags: pokemon-x-y

I picked Squirtle as my starter pokemon so I got the Blastoiseite. I spent a lot of time bringing down my style to get the venusaurite for $10,000 but I can't get the guy to sell me the Charizardite which is what I really want. Is there a certain wait period before he will sell the 2nd one? I believe i'm going on 5 days now it's been and he still only talks about the stone he already sold me. Anyone have any clue as I have yet to see this asked anywhere?

Comment: Wait, so you bought the Venusaurite and the option to buy the Charizardite isn't appearing?

Comment: Having the same issue. Is it possible that we need to wait until after the elite four?

Comment: @MadaraUchiha That may be the case. I bought both stones in succession after E4

Comment: yes @Haidro the option isn't appearing.

Comment: I can confirm your observations, it only makes sense that it doesn't become available until after beating the Elite Four.

Answer (score 3):

According to [this](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/137795/52519) answer, you must have defeated the Elite Four in order for the Stone Emporium man to sell you the other stone.

I also picked a squirtle, but only bought my stones after I beat the Elite Four. I bought the venasaurite first, then he immediately sold me the charizardite stone afterwards.

Comment: And regardless, you can't get the stone you got with your starter.

Comment: the problem with going with what it says in that link is that it tells you that you can't even get it down to 10,000 until after the Elite 4 which isn't true so I don't know what to believe